# Is there any way to not copy and paste the same stuff from @keyframes to @-webkit-keyframes in .css files?

Tags: css

I am not a CSS guru, so I use 3rd party CSS themes, and I only write casual CSS few lines. I have no CSS projects and build system, so not using any Sass or Less or SCSS build.

Is there any way to not copy and paste the same stuff from @keyframes to @-webkit-keyframes in my .css files?

Comment: You can automate prefixing with something like AutoPrefixer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-webkit` vendor prefix is not really needed anymore, the un-prefixed rule is now [supported](https://caniuse.com/css-animation) by most recent and older browsers.

So the short answer is just stop copy/pasting the vendor prefixed keyframes.